# duplicate url+content generation problem

Tags: url, seo

In my current site I have a link in the header section for skype, Gtalk, MSN chat, by clicking on the link the chat application get launched.
The problem is that, the link uses a href tag. and by doing this the SEO process is facing problem as there is some duplicate url have been created. In SEO process if different URLs have the same content the process not works.
Any suggestion from coming out from this problem.

Comment: And how exactly is this related to programming? gotoAndStop( http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ )

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to remedy this is add this adding a  element with the attribute `rel="canonical"` to the  section of the non-canonical version of the page.

More information please go to http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394

Answer (score 0):

make them js url (with the js function in an external script)